# Рекурсия. Метод pow()

Tags: java, рекурсия

Что не так?

```
class Sample2 {
  public static int pow(int x, int y) {
    int result = 1;
    if (y > 0) {
      result *= x;
      y--;
      pow(x, y);
    }
    return result;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(pow(2, 3));
    System.out.println(pow(3, 2));
  }
}
```

Выдает неправильный ответ, точнее только x.

Comment: "и поэтому лучше давайте развернутые вопросы" - это скорее к вам относится! А что не так в вашем коде?

Comment: Вы никак не используете результат рекурсивного вызова.

Comment: По невнимательности перепутал слова

Comment: А  почему не написать просто `return (y == 0) ? 1 : x * pow(x, y - 1);`?

Comment: Да, что не так? В чем проблема?

Comment: побпробуйте сами запустить

Comment: Нет, это вы должны описать в вопросе в чем проблема, а не мы должны запускать и гадать.

Comment: @senior Эникей правильно сказал, опишите проблему.

Comment: выдает неправильный ответ, точнее только x

Comment: @senior Обращайтесь через @, вас так никто не услышит.

Comment: Описание проблемы должно быть включено в вопрос, а не в комментари. Я добавил это за вас.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При каждом вызове `pow()` результат сбрасывается на 1. Строчку `int result = 1;` нужно вынести за пределы функции.

Но лучше всего вообще избавиться от дополнительной переменной, от нее только проблемы. Допустим, так (постарался внести как можно меньше изменений в ваш код):

```
public static int pow(int x, int y) {
    if (y > 0) {
        y--;
        return (x * pow(x, y));
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Проблема Вашего кода в том, что каждый раз при исполнение кода функции в результате Вы получите постоянное число `result *= x`, а сам результат получен из `pow(x, y)` игнорируется.

Еще один момент. Начальное значение `result` должно быть равно `x`, т.к. суть самой функции в том, чтобы повторится `y`-ковое кол-во раз.

```
public static int pow(int x, int y) {
    int result = 1;
    if (y > 0) {
        result = x * pow(x, --y); // Уменьшаем каждый раз y перед тем, как передать в параметр функции
    }
    return result;
}
```

Что по сути является более детальной версией `return (y == 0) ? 1 : x * pow(x, y - 1)` (чтобы не создавать отдельную переменную, без которой все выглядит еще проще).