# Как возвести 2 в степень i без pow

Tags: c++, c

Как возвести 2 в степень i. Запрещено использовать pow

Comment: Тупо множить в цикле.

Comment: А чужой код сдавать разрешено?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909078/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-pow/909087#909087

Comment: экспонента логарифма.

Comment: `frexp`,`ldexp` или `<<`. Читайте мануал.

Comment: Сдвигом, разумеется. Вся суть вопроса в этом. О какой "экспоненте" и "тупом множить" вы ведете речь?

Comment: @AnT, а если число с плавающей запятой, то есть `i` - дробное? :)

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, если автор вопроса имел в виду целое число `i`, притом не слишком большое, то обычно это делается одной операцией

```
result = 1 << i;
```

Однако здесь нужно сделать много всяких проверок, зависящих от конкретной задачи. Например, если ожидаемый результат больше, чем позволяет разрядность типичных типов данных языка программирования. Если речь идет о больших `i`, то нужно применять длинную арифметику.

Если же `i` - дробное, то традиционно для этого используют несколько приёмов: редукция аргумента и последующий за ней метод Ньютона. Есть и другие варианты, но мне кажется, автору вопроса не это нужно.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int x = 2; //Число
    int y = 4; //Степень

    int out = x;

    for (int i = 1; i < y; i++)
    {
        out = out * x;
    }
    cout <<"ОТВЕТ: " << out << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А зачем вы вставили картинку? Какие отличия от кода ниже?